# Provided proxyUrl does not match the format protocol when run vaadin starter for the first time

Tags: vaadin

Help please, I am learning vaadin for the first time,

when a run the app I am having this error:

```
\: Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided proxyUrl does not match the format protocol://user:password@server:port nor protocol://server:port\] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided proxyUrl does not match the format protocol://user:password@server:port nor protocol://server:port
at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.installer.ProxyConfig$Proxy.\<init\>(ProxyConfig.java:193) \~\[flow-server-23.0.4.jar:23.0.4\]

\: Servlet.service() for servlet \[dispatcherServlet\] in context with path \[\] threw exception \[com.vaadin.flow.server.ServiceException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided proxyUrl does not match the format protocol://user:password@server:port nor protocol://server:port\] with root cause

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Provided proxyUrl does not match the format protocol://user:password@server:port nor protocol://server:port
at com.vaadin.flow.server.frontend.installer.ProxyConfig$Proxy.\<init\>(ProxyConfig.java:193) \~\[flow-server-23.0.4.jar:23.0.4\]
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your proxy configuration is flawed (as it says in the error message).
Check that it looks like this:

```
proxy=http://user:password@172.17.0.1:3128
https-proxy=http://user:password@172.17.0.1:3128
```

https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/configuration/node-js has a more in-depth explanation.

Comment: I don't know if i am doing wrong but as specified in documentation a proxy can be configured in this ways:
  system properties | {project directory}/.npmrc file | {user home directory}/.npmrc file | environment variables.
I added those configuration  in comment to application.properties and didnt work 
and  i did the same for the .npmrc file but is still the same error

Comment: application.properties is the Spring configuration
What does your .npmrc look like?